# Keeping a containing div the size of its image

Tags: html, css

I have a square image inside of a containing div, and want the containing div to have the same dimensions as the image. The size of the image varies and is thus not known in advance. Note in particular that the image is the only thing inside the div (well, not strictly true, but the other element is absolutely positioned and thus can basically be ignored).

The code I currently have is as follows:

```css
div.container, image {
    display: block;

    /* ensure enough room for other content in sidebar */
    max-height: calc((100vh - 12em)/2);

    /* don't allow image to escape sidebar boundaries */
    max-width: 256px;

    /* forces image to be square as it's originally square */
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
}

div.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

I've seen some posts about using `padding-bottom`; while that does make the containing div a square, it's not necessarily the same size as the image, since the height of the image can be forced to be much smaller than the height of the div.

Are there any clean solutions to this?

Comment: I'd prefer to not use Javascript unless there's no way to do this in CSS.

Comment: I presume you can't use display: inline-block or float it?

Comment: so you want a container containing just the image and fit to its size ? and if yes then does that not mean adding a border to the image ?

Comment: @wizzardmr42 Ooh, inline-block seems to work; will need a little adjustment to account for some side effects but that seems to solve the hard part. Thanks!

Comment: @samuel front no problem. Should be good as long as you don't need support in old browsers. You can check caniuse.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `display` property of the `.container` element to be `inline-block` instead of `block`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i can think of is `display:table` for the parent container and `display:table-cell` for the image wrapper.

Here is a simple example of a container that have the same dimensions as the image it holds.

(The container is with the dashed border)

```css
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    vertical-align:top;
}
section{
    display:table;
}
.image{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
  outline:5px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<section>
    
    <article class="image">
        <img src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg" width="240" height="240" alt="">
    </article>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.container {
    display:table;
}
```

Comment: What does it do? How does it help? Why don't you edit your snippet to be more visible?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the division and do not give its height and with, and put the image inside, division will take height and width automatically according the to dimensions of the image.